# Animate truncated text UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I made a UILabel, but it isn't large enough for the text that it needs to hold, so the text wil be truncated. How can i get the text to animate inside the UILabel, so that it will be readable?

This is the truncated text (On the left wil be an image, so move it to the right is not an option).
[image: The truncated text]

How can I animate the text so that it moves from right to left in the available space. Like on those LED information boards (http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Create-A-LED-LCD-Style-Text-Scroller-Using-jQuery-CSS/)

Answer (score 0):

This effect is called *marquee*. Check eg. [this](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel) solution, it's quite handy